# Xamarin Forms Android, hide the title bar border

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

How can I hide the border from the title bar in Xamarin Android? I am using Xamarin Forms & Following code is used in MainActivity.cs to hide the rest of the title bar.

```
[Activity(Label = "", MainLauncher = true, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {

        this.RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBarOverlay);

        base.OnCreate(bundle);



        //Transperent Action Bar 
        ActionBar.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
        ActionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.ParseColor("#000000ff")));
        ActionBar.SetStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.ParseColor("#000000ff"))); 

        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        SetPage(App.GetMainPage());
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems like I don't have to do anything specific in Android Project, using following code in xaml.cs OnAppearing method did the trick
 `//Hide Nav Bar 
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`

Answer (score 3):

Use this code

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
```

and i hope if this works for you

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use Theme for that

```
[Activity(Label = "", MainLauncher = true, Theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: sure, and let me know after that :) probably I can help you for more

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code in your styles.xml file in Droid Project. Setting the elevation to 0 dp is the main thing here.

```
 <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
 </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use your NavigationPage

```
    public HelloWorlPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this theme in your MainActivity.cs ,

```
[Activity (Label = "XXX", 
    Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light",
    WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan,
    ConfigurationChanges=global::Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation|global::Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize |
    global::Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden)]
```